# When I am trying to install Ubuntu for a dual boot, the drive I pick is showing more gigabytes than it actually is

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation, hard-drive

I am trying to make my laptop dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7. I have read several tutorials out there and once dabbled with Linux distributions years ago before there really was any tutorials, guides, etc. to help me.

So anyway, I have a machine with two hard disk drives. Both are 698 GB drives. The first one has Windows 7 on it and the partitions on it for recovery, HP tools, etc. It has four partitions on it already, but I wanted to install Ubuntu on the second hard disk drive anyway. The second hard drive has nothing at all on it. I never kept any data or anything on it. So when I run the Ubuntu installation off of my USB drive and select to set up my partitions for the installation myself (rather than letting it overwrite or install side by side) it only shows `sdc` which is the drive I wanted to install on.

I did not expect to see the other drive because it has four primary partitions on it already anyhow. The problem *(or may not be I'm just concerned)* is that it says `sdc` has **750** GB. However, that drive is only 698 GB maximum. It did say that `sdc` has 14 GB already used which is what Windows and [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) show me too. It did say it would unmount it during installation. So I'm pretty sure it's the correct drive, but I'm confused about the 750 GB.

I do not want the installation to accidentally start messing with my Windows 7 installation and files on the other hard drive. Another source of confusion is when I'm looking with GParted. I expected the first hard drive with the Windows 7 installation to show `sda1`, `sda2`, etc. for the installation, data, HP tools, recovery, etc. like tutorials on-line show me it should do. However, like HP tools is showing up as `sdd` and the recovery is `sdb`. While the second hard drive is `sdc`, not the `sdb` like I thought it should be named.

---

Anyway, I know I'm more of a newbie, but still... I just want to be sure, and then I can start learning more; now that there is so many more guides out there than there were 10 years ago.

Comment: Edit your question, and add the output from terminal of `sudo fdisk -lu` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's calculational "problem".

Hard Disk Creators are calculating with `1000` and computer with `1024`.

750*1000^3 = 750.000.000.000 Bytes
750.000.000.000 Bytes / 1024^3 = rd. 698,5 GiB (Gigabit binary Bytes)

i didn't read the rest of your text, because it's too long.

have a look on your hdd , I guess it's written 750GB on it, since there are no 698GB disk out.